SQL query to calculate elapsed times from process data and timestamps
From the sample data shown below, I need to write a SQL query to identify the elapsed time of both the individual task and the overall session (accumulated elapsed times of all the previous tasks).
The reference time for the overall session is identified by the Task "Start" fro the given session id.
Task    UID             sessionID   logTime
Start   170431926600021 1704319266  2024-01-03 22:01:06
Task-1  170431926700021 1704319266  2024-01-03 22:01:07
Start   170433797800098 1704337978  2024-01-04 03:12:58
Task-1  170433797900098 1704337978  2024-01-04 03:12:59
Start   170436928400009 1704369284  2024-01-04 11:54:44
Task-1  170436928500009 1704369284  2024-01-04 11:54:45
Task-2  170438477900098 1704337978  2024-01-04 16:13:00
Task-2  170448126700021 1704319266  2024-01-05 19:01:08
Task-2  170450248500009 1704369284  2024-01-06 00:54:46

The desired output would be something like this where the elapsed time is measured in seconds
    Task           UID  sessionID   logTime            Task elapsed time    total elapsed time
Start   170431926600021 1704319266  2024-01-03 22:01:06 0   0
Task-1  170431926700021 1704319266  2024-01-03 22:01:07 xxx xxx
Start   170433797800098 1704337978  2024-01-04 03:12:58 0   0
Task-1  170433797900098 1704337978  2024-01-04 03:12:59 xxx xxx
Start   170436928400009 1704369284  2024-01-04 11:54:44 0   0
Task-1  170436928500009 1704369284  2024-01-04 11:54:45 xxx xxx
Task-2  170438477900098 1704337978  2024-01-04 16:13:00 xxx xxx + xxx
Task-2  170448126700021 1704319266  2024-01-05 19:01:08 xxx xxx + xxx
Task-2  170450248500009 1704369284  2024-01-06 00:54:46 xxx xxx + xxx

(xxx) represents the number of seconds corresponding to the calculation described above. (I'm not sure what the exact values is!)

Can you add a tag for which DBMS you are using?

remove screenshots and provide the code/data as text also provide a fiddle for your table.also remove xxx and provide values that you are expecting

CREATE TABLE Example 
(
    Task    VARCHAR(512),
    UID VARCHAR(50),
    sessionID   VARCHAR(50),
    logTime DateTime
);

INSERT INTO Example (Task, UID, sessionID, logTime) VALUES
    ('Start',  '170431926600021', '1704319266', '2024-01-03 22:01:06'),
    ('Task-1', '170431926600021', '1704319266', '2024-01-03 22:01:07'),
    ('Start',  '170433797800098', '1704337978', '2024-01-04 03:12:58'),
    ('Task-1', '170433797800098', '1704337978', '2024-01-04  03:12:59'),
    ('Start',  '170436928400009', '1704369284', '2024-01-04 11:54:44'),
    ('Task-1', '170436928400009', '1704369284', '2024-01-04 11:54:45'),
    ('Task-2', '170433797800098', '1704337978', '2024-01-04 16:13:00'),
    ('Task-2', '170431926600021', '1704319266', '2024-01-05 19:01:08'),
    ('Task-2', '170436928400009', '1704369284', '2024-01-06 00:54:46');

SELECT * FROM Example

SELECT *
INTo #Start  
FROM Example
WHERE Task='Start'  
ORDER BY UID

SELECT * FROM #Start

SELECT e.UID,e.Task, s.logTime as StartTime, e.logTime, isnull(LAG(e.logTime) OVER(PARTITION BY e.UID ORDER BY (e.logTime)),s.logTime) as PreviouslogTime
INTO #Calculated 
FROM Example e
INNER JOIN #Start s on S.UID=e.uid  
WHERE e.Task!='Start'  

Select * FROM #Calculated

SELECT  c.UID,c.Task, c.logTime as StartTime, c.logTime, datediff(second, c.PreviouslogTime, c.logtime) as Elapsed, datediff(second, c.StartTime, c.logtime) as TotalElapsed
FROM  #Calculated c

fiddle

CTE version to follow

CTE version https://dbfiddle.uk/ZhD0AhmH
